# Ploty subplot per combination with spread

Tags: loops, plotly, finance, subplot

Using he prices of GOOG, AAPL, AMZN, FB, NFLX, MSFT and rebase all to 1.

I want to loop through each combination of two stocks, plot that, and then plot the spread between them.

Row 1) Two Charts: Col 1) Line plot of GOOG vs AAPL Col 2)  GOOG - AAPL chart

Row 2) Two Charts: Col 1) Line plot of GOOG vs AMZN Col 2)  GOOG - AMZN chart

Row 3) Two Charts: Col 1) Line plot of GOOG vs FB Col 2)  GOOG - FB chart

Have been trying to edit the example in the documentation but i'm struggling

```
 import plotly.express as px

 df = px.data.stocks(indexed=True)
 fig = px.line(df, facet_col="company", facet_col_wrap=2)
 fig.add_hline(y=1, line_dash="dot", row="all", col="all")

 fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

- taking an approach of structure data for plotting
- `df2` is a dataframe that is ideally shaped for `px.line()`
- no sample code,  so have used spread as the `abs()` of the difference
- this will generate pairs of traces for each combination of tickers (columns)

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks(indexed=True)

# structure data so it's simple to use in sub-plots
df2 = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.DataFrame(
            index=df.index,
            data={
                "row": np.full(len(df), f"{a} {b}"),
                "spread": (df[a] - df[b]).abs(), # an approach to spread
                "diff": df[a] - df[b],
            },
        )
        for a, b in itertools.combinations(df.columns, 2)
    ]
).pipe(
    lambda d: d.set_index(d["row"], append=True)
    .drop(columns=["row"])
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={0: "obs", "level_2": "col"})
)

fig = px.line(df2, x="date", y="obs", facet_row="row", facet_col="col")

# cleanup annotations
for a in fig.layout["annotations"]:
    a.update(text=a.text.split("=")[-1])
    
fig.update_layout(height=1800)
```

#### output

[image]